# Set EXIF DateTaken as file CreationTime

Tags: powershell, exif

I'm trying to fix metadata of my photos using powershell.
I need to set exif DateTaken as file CreationTime

Here is my code:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadfile( "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll")
echo "--------"
echo ""
$files = Get-ChildItem E:\Photos\*.*
ForEach ($file in $files) {

        #Get Date
    $foo=New-Object -TypeName system.drawing.bitmap -ArgumentList $file.fullname 
    $date = $foo.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[0..9]
    $arYear = [Char]$date[0],[Char]$date[1],[Char]$date[2],[Char]$date[3]  
    $arMonth = [Char]$date[5],[Char]$date[6]  
    $arDay = [Char]$date[8],[Char]$date[9]  
    $strYear = [String]::Join('',$arYear)  
    $strMonth = [String]::Join('',$arMonth)   
    $strDay = [String]::Join('',$arDay)  
    $DateTaken = $strDay + "/" + $strMonth + "/" + $strYear


        # Get Time
    $time = $foo.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[11..18]
    $arHour = [Char]$time[0],[Char]$time[1]
    $arMinute = [Char]$time[3],[Char]$time[4]  
    $arSecond = [Char]$time[6],[Char]$time[7]  
    $strHour = [String]::Join('',$arHour)  
    $strMinute = [String]::Join('',$arMinute)   
    $strSecond = [String]::Join('',$arSecond)  
    $TimeTaken = $strHour + ":" + $strMinute + ":" + $strSecond

        # Link into one date and time
    $FullDate = $DateTaken + " " + $TimeTaken

    echo "File name"
    echo $file.name
    echo ""
    echo "Wrong data"
    echo (Get-Item $file).creationtime.datetime
    echo ""
    echo "Right data"
    echo $FullDate
    echo ""

        #Set DateTaken as CreationTime 
    (Get-Item $file).creationtime= $FullDate

    pause
}
```

I got error "cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".
I have no idea how to fix it.

PS. I'm not sure if `$FullDate` has right syntax, because I couldn't test it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried get rid of the $foo object by calling $foo.dispose()?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @TomG, that solved my problem
I already finished this project. I post code, this may help someone with fixing dates in photos in future

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadfile( "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll")
Clear-Host
$files = Get-ChildItem E:\Photos\*.*
$i = 1
ForEach ($file in $files) {

        # Print file name
    echo $file.fullname 

        # Print Number of File
#   Write-Host 'File no: ' $i
#   echo ""

        #Get Date
    $foo=New-Object -TypeName system.drawing.bitmap -ArgumentList $file.fullname
    $date = $foo.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[0..9]
    $arYear = [Char]$date[0],[Char]$date[1],[Char]$date[2],[Char]$date[3]  
    $arMonth = [Char]$date[5],[Char]$date[6]  
    $arDay = [Char]$date[8],[Char]$date[9]  
    $strYear = [String]::Join('',$arYear)  
    $strMonth = [String]::Join('',$arMonth)   
    $strDay = [String]::Join('',$arDay)  

#       Date to string
#   $DateTaken = $strDay + "/" + $strMonth + "/" + $strYear


        # Get Time
    $time = $foo.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[11..18]
    $arHour = [Char]$time[0],[Char]$time[1]
    $arMinute = [Char]$time[3],[Char]$time[4]  
    $arSecond = [Char]$time[6],[Char]$time[7]  
    $strHour = [String]::Join('',$arHour)  
    $strMinute = [String]::Join('',$arMinute)   
    $strSecond = [String]::Join('',$arSecond)  

    $foo.dispose()

#       Time to string
#   $TimeTaken = $strHour + ":" + $strMinute + ":" + $strSecond

    $NewDate = (Get-Date -Year $strYear -Month $strMonth -Day $strDay -Hour $strHour -Minute $strMinute -Second $strSecond)

        #Set DateTaken as CreationTime 
    (Get-Item $file).CreationTime = $NewDate
    (Get-Item $file).LastWriteTime = $NewDate

    $i++

#   Clear-Host
}

echo ""
echo "Done"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Transferring my images from Flickr I had the same issue ... with the help of the above and a few other online sources I came up with

```bsh
# ==============================================================================================
# 
# UPDATE: Sam Ellis - @elliz
# DATE: 08 February 2018
# COMMENT: Added dispose, simplified date extraction, added error cases and tests
# COMMENT: Also edits file create and update date based on Image Taken EXIF data
# COMMENT: Added progress
# 
# UPDATED: Steve Smith - @ardalis
# DATE: 18 January 2009
# COMMENT: Changed file paths and confirmed it works.  Note that file extension must be .psONE not .psELL
#
# AUTHOR:  Kim Oppalfens, 
# DATE  : 12/2/2007
# 
# COMMENT: Helps you organise your digital photos into subdirectory, based on the Exif data 
# found inside the picture. Based on the date picture taken property the pictures will be organized into
# [directory script called from]\YYYY\YYYY-MM-DD
# ============================================================================================== 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$imageSourcePath = Get-Location
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $imageSourcePath -filter *.jpg  # -recurse
$numFiles = $files.Count
[Int32]$counter = 0
[Int32]$takenDatePropertyId = 36867

foreach ($file in $files) {

    $takenDate = $Null
    $counter++
    Write-Progress "$numFiles image files." -PercentComplete (100 * $counter / $numFiles)

    $image = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList $file.FullName
    [string]$targetPath = $Null

    try {
        $takenDateExists = $image.PropertyIdList -Contains $takenDatePropertyId
        if (-Not $takenDateExists) {
            Write-Warning "File '$( $file.Name )' has no taken date EXIF. Moving to 'Unknown' folder."
            $targetPath = Join-Path $imageSourcePath "Unknown"
        }
        Else {
            $dateCharArray = $image.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value[0..18]  # Omitting last null character from array
            [String]$dateString =  [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($dateCharArray)
            $takenDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss', $Null)

            $targetPath = Join-Path $imageSourcePath "$( Get-Date $takenDate -Format yyyy )\$( Get-Date $takenDate -Format yyyy-MM-dd )"
        }

        $image.Dispose()

        If (-Not (Test-Path $TargetPath)) {
            New-Item $TargetPath -Type Directory | Out-Null
        }

        # Change create date to taken date
        if ($Null -ne $takenDate) {
            $file.CreationTime = $takenDate
        }

        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $targetPath | Out-Null
        # xcopy /Y/Q $file.FullName $TargetPath | Out-Null # this creates new item with new create date

    }
    catch {
        $err = $_
        Write-Error "Error processing image $( $file.Name ):/r/n$err"

        if ($Null -ne $image) {
            $image.Dispose()
        }
    }


} 

Write-Output "Finished moving $numFiles files from $imageSourcePath"
```

Trigger the script from an Admin PowerShell shell whilst in the directory your photos are in and enjoy.