# How to delete all images in a folder taken at certain time using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete all images within a folder taken between 8pm and 7am Using Powershell but I'm having some trouble. Unfortunately the information on the images do not have the correct date modified/ date created time but the correct time is stored in the image metadata as Date Taken.

I've tried this

```
get-ChildItem *jpg | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay.Hours -gt 20 -or $_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay.Hours -lt 07} |Remove-Item
```

But this deletes everything because the write time is 11pm for all the images. (the image taken date is different for the images)

I have about 3,000 images to sort through. I'm very new to powershell, but it seems like it should work. I can also use Python if people think thats easier...

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the EXIF data (metadata) from inside each image file. Get-ChildItem is only going to return the properties of the file itself, not any metadata inside the file.

Checkout this Microsoft article that describes the process [using a COM object to expose the EXIF fields of an image](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/) (including `Date Taken`). This solution requires a [PowerShell function on the technet gallery to actually fetch the EXIF data.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding another code that assigns the Date Taken to the Date Created property. So then I could run the original code I posted. I dont really need anything efficient so this got the job done.

[Set EXIF DateTaken as file CreationTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685407/set-exif-datetaken-as-file-creationtime)